# Can I talk to people without digging up their past?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm in Gilded Vale. There are several NPCs whom I can interact with, but when I do I'm all overcome by spirits 'n stuff.

Is there any way to interact with these people without the visions of the (presumed) past getting in the way?

Comment: I wondered the same thing, I haven't found a way yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think so; the NPC's with little Soul Vignettes are, I *think* basically the result of a Kickstarter pledge reward:

> NAME AND DESIGN AN NPC (Non-Player Character). Help us design PROJECT ETERNITY! We will send you a PROJECT ETERNITY NPC character sheet for you to fill out for our design team. We will turn your personalized character design, with your name, class, and race into an NPC in the shipped game (within reason of course)

Based on the Kickstarter, there's about ~115 of these, and while they provide some nice lore, they aren't gameplay objectives.